# how to select minimum no. of items from an array to get absolute diff b/w sum and x

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

given an array and value of x. I need an fastest algorithm or code for finding minimum no. of items to pick from the array so that abs diff b/w sum of those items and value of x is minimum. I used recursive function.

```
public class Demo {

    static int[] solve(int arr[], int i, int esum, int csum, int size) {

        if (i == 0) {
            return new int[]{Math.abs(esum - csum), size};
        }

        int a1[] = solve(arr, i - 1, esum, csum + arr[i - 1], size + 1);
        int a2[] = solve(arr, i - 1, esum, csum, size);

        if (a1[0] < a2[0]) {
            return a1;
        } else if (a1[0] > a2[0]) {
            return a2;
        } else {
            if (a1[1] < a2[1]) {

                return a1;
            } else {
                return a2;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //x = 108
        int arr[] = new int[]{70, 30, 33, 23, 4, 4, 34, 95, -50, -10, -10, -7};
        int a[] = solve(arr, arr.length, 108, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(a[0] + " " + a[1]);

    }
}
```

output should be 0,3 (abs dif b/w items picked and x),(no. of items picked)

1st pref to min abs dif if we have many subsets have same abs diff pick the one having less no. of items